# Sencha Touch defferend method similar to jQuery

Tags: extjs

Does Sencha Touch has a similar method to jquery defferend?

```
$.when(

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request),

  // Deferred object (probably Ajax request)

).then(function() {

  // All have been resolved (or rejected), do your thing

});
```

Let's say, wait for 3 stores to load and do something after?

Comment: no, I had the exact same requirement and had to write something on my own for it

Comment: It won't be hard, but I'll have to go from one callback to another, and the could would be less optimized and readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my sample code:

```
Ext.getStore('Store1').load({ callback: createGrid });
Ext.getStore('Store2').load({ callback: createGrid });

var loadedStores = 0;
function createGrid() {
    loadedStores = loadedStores + 1;

    if (loadedStores === 2) {
        grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.panel', {
            ...
        });
    )
}
```

not nice but it works and is scalable.